# Using Jenkins Pipline Script to checkout Repo and build docker image, but it occures error

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I use Jenkins Pipeline Script to checkout git repo and build docker image

the script code looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        imageName = 'jenkins_project'
        dockerImage = ''
        registry = 'openshipft_registry'
    }
    agent { label "${config.job.agent}" }
    stages {
      stage('Prepare') {
                steps {
                    echo "CheckOut"
                    script {
                        sh """
            git checkout origin/$branch
        """
                    }
                   
                }
            }
        stage('Building image') {
                steps{
                    script {
                        dockerImage = docker.build imageName  + ":$BUILD_NUMBER"
                    }
                }
            }
        stage('Deploy Image'){
                steps {
                    script {
                       docker.withRegistry(registry) {
                           dockerImage.push()
                       } 
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

but I got an error:

- docker build -t project:10 .
  /home/jenkins/project/workspace/xxxx/script.sh: 1: /home/jenkins/project/workspace/xxx/script.sh: docker: not found

any solutions?

Comment: Just add the Jenkins user to docker group so that jenkins can access docker-deamon. `sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins`

Comment: Hi, How should I add this command into Jenkins Pipeline Script???

Comment: can you give more details, because I dont use this comment in my jenkins pipeline, I have only Dockerfile and Docker compose yml.

Comment: Yeah got it. I have not checked the pipeline properly. Could you please look into this [post](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-not-found-in-jenkins-pipeline/31683/14) Hope this will be helpful. The possible solution I can think is to mount `/var/run/docker.sock` which is mentioned in the post as well.

Comment: hI I see this document, but I can not understand how to use this in my case. because I use in my case only jenkins pipeline script to build docker image, there is no any sudo commands...